# How to make calculations based on insertion of fields in the reactjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, reactjs, calc

```
      handleContractValueChange(e) {
  this.setState({ currency: e.target.value });
    console.log(e.target.value);
 }

handleSubscrtiptionAmountChange(e) {
    this.setState({ subscriptionamount: e.target.value });
    console.log(e.target.value);

}

 handleQuarterPercentageChange(e){
    this.setState({Quarterpercentage: e.target.value});
   console.log(e.target.value);

  }




  <div className="form-group row">

<label className="col-sm-2 form-control-label text-xs-right"> Contract Value: </label>
<div className="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" className="form-control box_ip" placeholder="Contract Amount" id="Contract Value" onChange={this.handleContractValueChange} value={this.state.currency} />
</div>

   <label className="col-sm-2 form-control-label text-xs-right"> Monthly Subscription Amount Payback percent</label>
    <div className="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" className="form-control box_ip" placeholder="SGD" id="Subscription Amount" onChange={this.handleSubscrtiptionAmountChange} name='Subscription Amount' value={this.state.subscriptionamount} />
    </div>
</div>

<div>
<label className="col-sm-2 form-control-label text-xs-right"> Monthly Subscription amount Payback: </label>
<div className="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" className="form-control box_ip" placeholder="Monthly Subscription amount Payback" id="Monthly Subscription amount Payback" onChange={this.handleQuarterPercentageChange} value={this.state.Quarterpercentage} /> </div>    

</div>
```

I have three fields Contract Value,Monthly Subscription Amount Payback percent, Monthly Subscription amount Payback based on filling Contract Value,Monthly Subscription Amount Payback percent third field(Monthly Subscription amount Payback) should be filled automatically.

Let us example if i fill contract value has 1000
Monthly Subscription Amount Payback percent is 2(it is in percentage[based on contract value and Monthly Subscription Amount Payback Quarterpercentage third field should fill automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbcTJ.png))

then Subscription Amount Payback should be auto filled with 1000/100 * 2 = 20 so 20 will be filled in the Subscription Amount Payback

Comment: You can set the value of third field on the `onChange` of the first 2 fields based on whether the fields are available or not.

Comment: i need to calculate the third value and i should populate please help me in calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value of third field on the `onChange`

```
handleContractValueChange(e) {
      let Quarterpercentage = 0;
      if(this.state.subscriptionamount > 0) {
         Quarterpercentage = (this.state.subscriptionamount * e.target.value)/100;       
       }
      this.setState({ 
         currency: e.target.value,
         Quarterpercentage
      });
        console.log(e.target.value);
     }
```

You can do the same for `handleSubscrtiptionAmountChange`.

```
handleSubscrtiptionAmountChange(e) {
      let Quarterpercentage = 0;
      if(this.state.currency > 0) {
         Quarterpercentage = (this.state.currency * e.target.value)/100;       
       }

    this.setState({ 
      subscriptionamount: e.target.value,
      Quarterpercentage
    });
    console.log(e.target.value);

}
```

Comment: Also you should change the input type to number as the inputs can be only number

Comment: no need to insert in the onchange on handleSubscrtiptionAmountChange

Comment: @user9196877 No, As that value should be calculated automatically, right ?

Comment: no, handleQuarterPercentageChange should be autocalculated

Comment: can you send moth the change functions with calculation too

Comment: handleSubscrtiptionAmountChange(e) {
      let Quarterpercentage = 0;
      if(this.state.subscriptionamount > 0) {
        Quarterpercentage = (subscriptionamount*e.target.value)/100;       
       }
      this.setState({ 
         subscriptionamount: e.target.value,
         Quarterpercentage
      });
        console.log(e.target.value);
     }

Comment: after changing both the change methods after entering contract value Quarterpercentage is getting 0 after filling subscriptionamountpayback percent Quarterpercentage  not getting changed. not getting calculated